# ArrayList to Convert into two dime Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, arraylist

I really need your help.
My problem is I need to convert an arraylist into two dime array. 
the arraylist came from a JSON.stringify and pass it to the Webmethod which handled by the ArrayList
//JSON File

```
    var noOfPstn = $("input[id$='txtPSTNOrderNum']").val();
    var newvale = [];
    var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfPstn; i++) {
        $("table[id$='PSTNOrder'] tr:eq('1') td:eq(3) input:checkbox:checked").each(function (r) {
            newvale.push([i], [$(this).val()]);
            counter++;
        });
    }

   // alert(newvale);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "NewPSTN.aspx/Sample",
        data: "{ 'Values': " + JSON.stringify(newvale) + ", rows:" + noOfPstn + ", ticks:"+(counter)+" }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { }
    });

 //WebMethod
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static void Sample(ArrayList Values,int rows, int ticks)
    {
        String[,] myValues = new String[rows,ticks];
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you show the json data sample

Comment: Could you please provide the expected result? How would you like to get the output in multi dime array?

Comment: Hi Mr Gagan Jauran

for Example the values in newvale = [];


newvale[0][0] = 'Line Sample'
newvale[0][1] = 'Line Plan'
newvale[0][2] = 'Line Plot'
newvale[1][0] = 'Plane Sample'
newvale[1][0] = 'Plane Plan'


those values found on newvale will be pass into a json file and will be process by JSON.stringify and pass it to the webmethod which handles by ArrayList Values